# changing links doesnt work with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this link:

```
<a href="http://iml.com/wmaster.ashx?WID=124904080515&amp;cbname=liveealve&amp;LinkID=701&amp;queryid=138&amp;from=freevideo6&amp;promocode=BETLNK&amp;FRefID=-1&amp;FRefP=none&amp;FRefQS=none" rel="nofollow" title="Visit imLive.com" target="_blank" class="sitelink_external imlive">Visit imLive.com</a>
```

I want to use this code to add/change different url parameters:

```
 $("a.sitelink_external.imlive").each(function(){
    $params=getUrlVars(document.URL);
       var promocode_addition='';
      if('INFO'==$params['ref']){
            promocode_addition='LCI';

      } 
    $(this).attr("href", 'http://im.com/wmaster.ashx?WID=124904080515&cbname=limdeaive&LinkID=701&queryid=138&promocode=LCDIMLRV" + i + promocode_addition+"&"FRefID=" + FRefID + "&FRefP=" + FRefP + "&FRefQS=" + FRefQS');

});
```

The problem is that that jquery code doesnt work..I tried to move it to document ready..but it doesnt work there too..

Comment: Are the `<a href>` in the HTML DOM are are they dynamic?

Comment: well,, on the server yeah..not on the client

Comment: your mixing of double and single quotes is making my brain hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that jumps out at me is that you're mixing your double and single quotes on this line:

```
$(this).attr("href", 'http://im.com/wmaster.ashx?WID=124904080515&cbname=limdeaive&LinkID=701&queryid=138&promocode=LCDIMLRV" + i + promocode_addition+"&FRefID=" + FRefID + "&FRefP=" + FRefP + "&FRefQS=" + FRefQS');
```

Try changing them all to double quotes, and remove the extra `"` from after the ampersand in `"&"FRefID="` - like this:

```
$(this).attr("href", "http://im.com/wmaster.ashx?WID=124904080515&cbname=limdeaive&LinkID=701&queryid=138&promocode=LCDIMLRV" + i + promocode_addition+"&FRefID=" + FRefID + "&FRefP=" + FRefP + "&FRefQS=" + FRefQS);
```

The way you had it was a single string containing stuff that looked like code. The way I've changed it is several strings and variables being concatenated together... (Note the difference with StackOverflow's syntax highlighting.)

Note also that the following code:

```
$params=getUrlVars(document.URL);
   var promocode_addition='';
  if('INFO'==$params['ref']){
        promocode_addition='LCI';

  }
```

...can be moved to *before* the `.each()` loop, since it operates only on the `document` and thus will produce the same results on every iteration.

(Of course there could be other problems since you reference several variables that aren't shown.)

Comment: I dont think that it is the solution...i changed it..is their a way to make the javascript override other javascript code..I think that might be the problem

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about overriding other code. Your `.each()` loop would need to be in a document ready (or at the bottom of the body after all the elements it processes). But given that you haven't said whether "doesn't work" means "does something but not the right thing" or "does nothing" or "shows various errors in the console" I'm not sure what else I can suggest...

Comment: Cool. And sorry, I just noticed I'd left an extra `"` at the end just before the closing `)` - I've updated my answer to remove it.